# What is difference between timestamp[ns] timestamp[s]?

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, parquet

I am reading the schema of parquet and JSON files to generate a DDL for a redshift table. I am getting some data types like `timestamp[ns]` and `timestamp[s]`. I tried to look upon the internet but couldn't understand the difference.
Can you please make me understand with some examples?

Comment: Added some examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

timestamp[x] is expressed in units x.

For you, s=seconds, ns=nanoseconds

For example:

Timestamp[s] = 2020-03-14T15:32:52

Timestamp[ms] = 2020-03-14T15:32:52.192

Timestamp[us] = 2020-03-14T15:32:52.192548

Timestamo[ns]= 2020-03-14T15:32:52.192548165

Comment: does that mean , something like  12-20-1995 12:11:11 [this is s] and 12-20-1995 12:11:11.111 [this is ns] ?

Comment: @Atif no, your second example is milliseconds - 1e-3. Nanoseconds are one billionth of a second - 1e-9. `12-20-1995 12:11:11.123456789`

Comment: @Atif what MattDMo said

Comment: @MattDMo ,Bey Thanks you mate. Got it finally.